# A filter $G$ on $P$ is generic iff whenever $W$ is a partition of $P$, $G \cap W \not = \emptyset$

Tags: set-theory, filters, forcing

I'm finally struggling a little bit with the notion of forcing, so I decided to do some of the exercises in Jech's book (2nd Edition) in order to sharpen a little bit my intuitions about the whole thing. Anyway, I'm stuck a little bit on exercise 16.5 (14.5 in the new edition, I believe), so I'd appreciate some help here. First, however, some definitions (I'll omit the references to the ground model $M$ here, as I don't think they're relevant to the exercise at hand; basically, everything except the generic filter is assumed to be in $M$).

Let $\langle P, \leq \rangle$ be a partial order. If $p, q \in P$ are such that there is an $r \in P$ and both $r \leq p$ and $r \leq q$, we say that $p$ and $q$ are *compatible*; otherwise, they are *incompatible*. A *cover* $C$ of $P$ is a set such that for every $p \in P$, there is a $q \in C$ such that $p$ and $q$ are compatible. A a set $F \subseteq P$ is a *filter* if:

> $F \not = \emptyset$;
>   if $p \in F$ and $p \leq q$, then $q \in F$;
>   if $p, q \in F$, then there is an $r \in F$ such that $r \leq p$ and $r \leq q$.

A filter $G$ on $P$ is called *generic* iff $G \cap C \not = \emptyset$ whenever $C$ is a cover of $P$.

Now define a *partition* $W$ of $P$ as a subset of $P$ such that $W$ is a cover of $P$ and for any distinct $p, q \in W$, $p$ and $q$ are incompatible. I'm asked to prove: a filter $G$ on $P$ is generic iff $G \cap W \not = \emptyset$ whenever $W$ is a partition of $P$. From left to right is immediate from the definition of generic: if $G \cap C \not = \emptyset$ whenever $C$ is a cover of $P$, then *a fortiori* $G \cap W \not = \emptyset$ whenever $W$ is a partition of $P$, as every partition of $P$ is, by definition, a cover of $P$. The side that is bugging me is from right to left. Here's what I got so far:

Let $p \in G \cap W$ and suppose $C$ is an arbitrary cover of $P$. Since $C$ is a cover of $P$, there is a $q \in C$ such that $p$ and $q$ are compatible, i.e. there is an $r$ such that $r \leq p$ and $r \leq q$. But $W$ is also a cover of $P$, so there must be an $s \in W$ such that $s$ and $q$ are compatible, i.e. there's a $t$ such that $t \leq s$ and $t \leq q$. Now, suppose $q < p$. Since $t \leq q$, by transitivity it follows that $t < p$, whence $p$ and $s$ are compatible. But that contradicts the fact that $p, s \in W$. So it's impossible for $q < p$.

From the above, I'd like to conclude that $p \leq q$, so that $q \in G$ and, hence, $G \cap C \not = \emptyset$, which would finish the proof. However, I only have a partial order, not a total order. Thus, it could be the case that $p$ and $q$ are incomparable, blocking the conclusion. So I'm beginning to think that my strategy may be wrong. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Why are you working with old editions of Jech?

Comment: Actually, I'm working with both. I found the second edition to be more manageable at some parts. Plus, it has some exercises that are not in the third edition (mainly on the forcing relation), which I wanted to try my hand at.

Comment: In modern terms, "cover" means "pre-dense" and "partition" means "maximal antichain".

Comment: @AsafKaragila - I noticed the disparity in the terminology, but didn't make too much of it; do you think I should update the post accordingly? I mean, is it potentially confusing?

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary, the comments are there to clarify, and any change would have me change my answer. And I think it's time I go to sleep already. On the other hand, it's a fresh question so bumping is not an issue, and you can always suggest an edit to my answer if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** Suppose that $C$ is a cover, well-order it as $\{p_\alpha\mid\alpha<\lambda\}$ and by transfinite recursion, define a partition.

(The axiom of choice is essential, since without the axiom of choice, it might be that a partial order has no partitions, so every filter is vacuously generic by the second definition.)

Comment: Supposing my ground model is c.t.m., do I still need to use transfinite recursion (which would be transfinite recursion *inside* the model, I gather)? Or can I just work outside the model, enumerate it, and apply ordinary recursion?

Comment: No, you want to work inside the model. Otherwise there's no guarantee that the resulting antichain/partition is in the model to begin with.

Comment: Alright, I'll give this some more thought. It's more complicated than what I first thought.

Comment: No, it's not. It's the most straightforward use of transfinite recursion you can think of. It's just that transfinite recursion sounds complicated. But it's really not. You just choose the least element which is incompatible with all the previous ones.

Comment: Hmm. The base case and the successor case are obvious: the base case is the least $p_\alpha$ which is incompatible with its predecessors, and, for the successor case, throw it in the set if it's incompatible with the rest, otherwise not. As for the limit case, same as in the successor case? (By the way, $\lambda$ is the cardinal of $C$, right?)

Comment: This is really a "complete induction" type argument. So yeah, limit and successor cases are the same. And $\lambda$ is any ordinal of your model, not necessarily a cardinal.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. The rest is straightforward.